# Android: How to read a number as int from a String; basically to read Text of a ListViewItem?

Tags: android, integer, listviewitem, charsequence

This is my problem.

I have a **ListView**, each row is a **CheckedTextView**. 
The list view items are  "1", "2" and "3".
When a ListItem is clicked, I want to read the number and assign it to an **int** variable.
I did the following to read the Text of the clicked item:

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {             
  int num = 0; //initialise to 0
  CharSequence s = ((TextView)v).getText();
 // s contains the number, how to get it into num?
}
```

Basically, I want the number read in s to be converted and given to num. 
I know it maybe simple, but please help if you have an answer..

Regards,
Kiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String aString = "78";
int aInt = Integer.parseInt(aString);
```

Comment: Yes I got it from another question in StackOverflow. toString() function converts the CharSequence into String before using this code. So finally, num = Integer.parseInt(((TextView)v).getText().toString());